# Does parse support atomicity?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, parse-platform, paas

Suppose we have a mobile app using parse,and most of the users are trying to write to one PFObject at the same time, simultaneously some of the users are tying to read the value. Does parse support atomicity to prevent the corruption of data. Is there any guarantee that that PFObject will never be in an invalid state.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your design will generally not work the way you described. There is no mutual exclusion of beforeSave hooks, save operations, or afterSave hooks accessing the same objects.

The best alternative solution available to you depends on the specifics of your data semantics. However, in general, the solution will involve using atomic increment or array operations as described in the "Counters" and "Arrays" sections beneath here (or [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#objects-updating) [for iOS](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-updating/iOS), or [here for Android](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-updating)).

This question is also discussed in [Parse Forum](https://www.parse.com/questions/saving-and-atomicity)